# fix react GA href path

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a simple react app project with google analytics:

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga4";
import TagManager from "react-gtm-module";


useEffect(() => {
  ReactGA.initialize("G-xxxxx...");
  ReactGA.send("pageview");
  TagManager.initialize({
    gtmId: "GTM-x"xxxx...
  });
 }
}, []);

<a
 href={`${window.location.protocol}//${domain}`}
 target="_blank"
 rel="noreferrer noopener">
 {`${window.location.protocol}//${domain}`}
</a>
```

But this link in browser have a href like this:

```
<a href="https://test.com&amp;_gl=1*l68v33*_ga*ABRVALTRA.*_ga_1RTDSMNASHGFDTJSLJSNG.." target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">https://test.com</a>
```

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

p.s: This is mast be: `<a href="https://test.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">https://test.com</a>`

Comment: Where do you define the `domain` variable?

Comment: hi, i could help to fix it but you have to provide more code that include `domain` variable being defined and initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the link to the button:

```
          <Button
            variant="link"
            onClick={handleClickOnLink}>
            {`${window.location.protocol}//${domain}`}
          </Button>
```

And:

```
const href = `${window.location.protocol}//${domain}`;

  const handleClickOnLink = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(href, "_blank");
  };
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to check the setting in your `Google Analytics Setting`?

You might have configured the cross domain tracking from there and GA will add the `gl` and `_ga` parameter in the url href.

[GA4 Cross Domain Tracking Document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en)
[image]